# Is it possible to group or put multiple images inside a folder using xpages, like in FB photo albums?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

we have a client that wants to have an FB like photo album feature, where in the user can upload image(s) and put those uploaded or selected image(s) inside an album. I just want to know first if it's possible using out of the box xpage or I need to use a framework. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here's a link to the semi-unfinished "fileVault".  https://bitbucket.org/leedy/filevault  I'm trying to get this on notesin9.com. It is a framework that allows multiple files to be uploaded to a series of storage databases. Pictures are grouped via a key which would similar to your folder requirement.  Might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David, I will definitely look that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways are possible, it depends on your requirements.

Take a look at this OpenNTF project - Bildr: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/bildr

Comment: Wow, that really saves my blowing mind. I'm new in xpage so this one really helped me. I saw the screenshots and I think it suits well with the requirements that I have. Thank you very much! I will try this one out.

Comment: Can't make it work, don't know what is wrong. All my xpages are working except for this one. I get Error 500. I did checked the discussions and found that the same issue did exist before, but I haven't found and answers or reply. I thought this was it. Have you tried and made it work in your server @Frantisek?

Comment: No, I did not use it, I've just passed the info about it. You need to identify the problem - please search this site to collect Error 500 logs. Then use stacktrace to identify the cause (design signature, missing bean or something similarly trivial). post new question to help you with that, if needed.